# How to use Dart's Uri to parse links containing #

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use dart's uri to parse the following url, the value in the parameter contains a ”#“

```
String url = 'scheme://a.b.c/d?p={"url": "https://test.test.com/#/a/b"}';
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
var map = uri.queryParameters;
print(map);
```

I want to get the value of parameter *p* through uri analysis

The result of the above code is as follows:

```
{p: {"url": "https://test.test.com/}
```

The desired result is as follows:

```
{p: {"url": "https://test.test.com/#/a/b}
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. First, you replace `#` with a unique value. After parsing then again replace the hashtag.

```
String url = 'scheme://a.b.c/d?p={"url": "https://test.test.com/#/a/b"}';
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url.replaceAll("#","hashtag"));
var map = uri.queryParameters;
print(map.toString().replaceAll("hashtag","#"));
```

output: `{p: {"url": "https://test.test.com/#/a/b"}}`

Answer (score 0):

The hash `#` must be replaced with its encoded value `%23`:

```
String url = 'scheme://a.b.c/d?p={"url": "https://test.test.com/%23/a/b"}';
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you supplied should have had characters with special meanings escaped/encoded in the first place. `Uri.parse` probably is parsing it correctly; you just gave it malformed input for what you intended.

What you should do instead is to *encode* the argument for your query string first:

```dart
String queryArgument = '{"url": "https://test.test.com/#/a/b"}';
String encodedArgument = Uri.encodeQueryComponent(queryArgument);
String url = 'scheme://a.b.c/d?p=$encodedArgument';
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
var map = uri.queryParameters;
print(map); // Prints: {p: {"url": "https://test.test.com/#/a/b"}}
```